How does an Imp change shape into a boar?
So I was reading through the Imp stat block and saw it had the following line:

change shape (boar, giant spider, rat, or raven, beast shape I)

The change shape ability specifies though:

A creature cannot change shape to a form more than one size category smaller or larger than its original form.

The issue I see is that an Imp is tiny sized and a boar is medium sized which is more than one size category larger. Does the specific text of the imp stat block override the general rule for change shape?


Does the specific text of the imp stat block override the general rule for change shape?

Yes, it does. This is a pretty basic case of “specific trumps general,” which isn’t really a rule so much as the basic premise of the entire rules framework. There are general rules, and then specific game elements (e.g. imp, Power Attack, burning hands) are specific ways you’re allowed to break those rules. It’s basically sanctioned cheating :P
There is some ambiguity as to whether the imp can turn into Medium creatures from beast shape I, where the imp would pick things off of a more-general list. One might argue that the imp is restricted to Fine through Small creatures on that list here. This, unfortunately, is not terribly clear: change shape generally can’t change into a form two or more size categories larger, but the imp’s says it can use beast shape I and beast shape I says you can turn into Medium animals. Which one is more specific? They’re not clearly related to one another: the specific rule (the imp’s ability) references two general rules (change shape and beast shape I) that don’t have any obvious hierarchical relationship.
So that’s a bit of a mess, and a GM’ll have to make a judgment call on it. Ultimately, I’d probably just ignore the size restriction on change shape when the specified options (including references to spells and the like) are available. I’d only consider that restriction if something had “change shape (any X)” where X is some type or something.
